# Template template parameters and operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I want to overload the equality operator in the template class with template template parameters. The code:

```
template <typename TObj, template<typename T> class TDerived>
class A;

template <typename TObjL, template<typename T> class TDerivedL, typename TObjR, template<typename T> class TDerivedR>
bool operator==(const A<TObjL, TDerivedL>& l, const A<TObjR, TDerivedR>& r)
{
    return true;
}

template <typename TObj, template<typename T> class TDerived>
class A
{
    template <typename TObjL, template<typename T> class TDerivedL, typename TObjR, template<typename T> class TDerivedR>
    friend bool operator==(const A<TObjL, TDerivedL>& l, const A<TObjR, TDerivedR>& r);
};

template <typename TObj>
class B: public A<TObj, B>
{
};

int main()
{
    B<int> b1, b2;
    b1==b2;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler refuses to compile this code, giving me an error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=='. When I replace all template template parameters with type parameters (leaving only `class TDerived`, for example) there are no errors. Why does this error occur and what is the correct way of overloading operators in such classes?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91137d47bf6e2918), and I see no reason why this shouldn't compile. Which compiler are we talking about here?

Comment: @T.C. I'm using gcc 4.8.2 and 3.4.2.

Comment: Sounds like a GCC bug, then.